# how i can declare out in parameter in powershell like c#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have c# code and i want to find alternative of this code in PowerShell . I found something like `[ref]$parameter` but it's doesn't work . 
My code is :

```
private static bool testfunction(string param1, out string param 2)
{
    param1 = "";
    param2 += "Hello";
    return true;
}
```

Please give me alternative code in PowerShell.

i try this :

```
class tst 
{

    static test([ref]$param)
    {
        $param.Value  = "world "

    }
}

$test = "ddd"
$test

[tst]::test($test)
$test
```

this is doesn't work.

Comment: What PowerShell code are you using that doesn't work?

Comment: @BACON i use this command at top .

Comment: @Enigmativity this is not duplicit

Comment: @saftargholi - Why not?

Comment: @Enigmativity because i declare in class i want to know when i declare in class what happen to value . when i declare in class reference doesn't work.

Comment: @Enigmativity you can test it . and then mark as duplicate .and also out and ref has some different . if i use ref i should pass value to my parameter before use it . i don't want to pass any value to my parameter .

Comment: @Enigmativity thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function testfunction {
   param (
       [string]
       $param1,
       [ref]
       $param2
   )

   $param2.value= "World"
   return $true
}

PS C:\> $hello = "Hello"

PS C:\> testfunction "someString" ([ref]$hello)
True

PS C:\> $hello
World
```

Powershell supports *ref* parameters. Be sure to call the ref parameter in brackets (e.g. `([ref] $parameter`). Be also be aware to only declare `[ref]`as type in the `param`block. Further details:

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596634/how-to-define-named-parameter-as-ref-in-powershell)

[ss64](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-ref.html)

hope that helps

**UPDATE**

You've to call your test method with the ref keyword -> use `[tst]::test([ref]$test)` instead of `[tst]::test($test)

```
PS C:\> $test = "ddd"

PS C:\> $test
ddd

PS C:\> [tst]::test([ref]$test)

PS C:\> $test
world
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is not my answer . i wanna declare ref in class and use it out or class .

Comment: Sorry, I understood it in a wrong way. You've to call your `test` method with the **ref** keyword -> use `[tst]::test([ref]$test)` instead of `[tst]::test($test)`.

Answer (score 0):

use `[ref]` when you use class :

```
class tst 
{

    static test([ref]$param)
    {
        $param.Value  = "world "

    }
}

$test = "ddd"
$test

[tst]::test([ref]$test)
$test
```