# Module scope gets duplicated for every script

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a module, and script which runs simple user scripts. I want to keep user script as simple as possible, and that's why I use `Import-Module` with `-Global` flag. I have a problem with module "private" variable. In my case I have 2 copies of this variable. Can I achieve only one copy?

Below is simple example. You can run in by placing 3 files in the same folder and executing `ScriptRunner.ps1`.

**Module.psm1**

```
function Invoke-UserScript
{
    param($Path)

    $Script:UserScriptFailed = $false
    & $Path
    return $Script:UserScriptFailed
}

function New-Something
{
    $Script:UserScriptFailed = $true
}

function Write-Var
{
    Write-Host "Write-Var output: $Script:UserScriptFailed"
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Invoke-UserScript
Export-ModuleMember -Function New-Something
Export-ModuleMember -Function Write-Var
```

**ScriptRunner.ps1**

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
Import-Module -Name (Resolve-Path '.\Module.psm1') -Global
$failed = Invoke-UserScript -Path '.\UserScript.ps1'
Write-Output "ScriptRunner output: $failed"
```

**UserScript.ps1**

```
New-Something
Write-Var
```

In my example function `New-Something` sets `UserScriptFailed` to `$true`. But once `UserScript.ps1` finishes, `ScriptRunner.ps1` sees `$false` value.

Output:

```
Write-Var output: True
ScriptRunner output: False
```

Comment: This is to be expected - `$script:` refers to the module scope when called from within a module's exported function, and `ScriptRunner.ps1` is not part of the module

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `ScriptRunner.ps1` is not part of the module, and it is not referring to `UserScriptFailed` variable, we are ok here. The problem is `& $Path` creates new copy of this variable. And this line is within a module.

Comment: You could maybe use `Export-ModuleMember -Variable ...`, but I'm not sure how this will work the `script:` scope. Another way could be to move `UserScriptFailed` to `global`-scope, but that's not the best joice ...

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want to share a variable between multiple ps1-files you can try to inject to variable as a [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596634/how-to-define-named-parameter-as-ref-in-powershell)-parameter

Comment: @Moerwald I want to validate user script by using my module. User creates simple script with commands from my module (I parse his script and check if he uses only allowed commands). In short I want to achieve 2 `True` values in my output.

Comment: @Moerwald global variable or exported variable is bad, since user can access it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193276/discussion-between-moerwald-and-zergatul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to dot source the script you want to check:

```
function Invoke-UserScript
{
    param($Path)

    $Script:UserScriptFailed = $false
    # Sourcing may add the functions to the current scope
    . $Path
    & $Path
    return $Script:UserScriptFailed
}
```