# How to define "named" parameter as [ref] in PowerShell (really this time)

Tags: powershell

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596634/how-to-define-named-parameter-as-ref-in-powershell), but neither answer actually answers the question using *named* argument in the call to the function

This is for Powershell 7. No workflow. And really Named Parameters this time! Also not covered in the standard documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-7.1) .. Starting to think that this isn't possible.

this works, but it is requires brackets with positional arguments, not named arguments

```
Function MyFunction ([ref][string]$MyRefParam) {
    $MyRefParam.Value = "newValue";
}
$myLocal = "oldValue"
Write-Host $myLocal  # Outputs: oldValue
MyFunction ([ref]$myLocal);
Write-Host $myLocal # Outputs: newValue
```

Of course we all know that the best way to call a Powershell function is with named argument `MyFunction -Arg1 23` rather than positional arguments `MyFunction 23` or `MyFunction(23)` . These would not get through our Pull Requests!

But this doesn't work

```
Function MyFunction ([ref][string]$MyRefParam) {
    $MyRefParam.Value = "newValue";
}
$myLocal = "oldValue"
Write-Host $myLocal  # Outputs: oldValue
MyFunction -MyRefParam ([ref]$myLocal) # Outputs Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'MyRefParam'. Reference type is expected in argument.
Write-Host $myLocal # Outputs: oldValue
```

Is there another way to provide the ref type in this syntax? So far I've tried combinations of [ref] and [ref][string] in both the param definition and in the call - I can't get anything to let Powershell see that I am really passing a Ref

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So the only purpose of using [ref] is to force function calls to use the actual parameter name to ease you code reviews?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use *only* a `[ref]` type constraint in your parameter declaration**, i.e. remove the additional `[string]` type constraint (it doesn't do anything, and arguably shouldn't even be allowed - see bottom section):

```sh
Function MyFunction ([ref] $MyRefParam) {
    $MyRefParam.Value = "newValue"
}

$myLocal = 'oldVaue'
MyFunction -MyRefParam ([ref] $myLocal)
$myLocal # -> 'newvalue'
```

You cannot *type* a `[ref]` instance: `[ref]` isn't a *keyword* that modifies a parameter declaration (as `ref` would be in C#), it is a *type in its own right*, [`System.Management.Automation.PSReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSReference), and its value-holding property, `.Value` is of type `object`, i.e. it can hold *any* type of object.

The upshot:

- You cannot enforce a specific data type when a value is passed via `[ref]`.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Conversely, you're free to assign a value of any type to the `.Value` property of the `[ref]` instance received.

**Taking a step back**:

- **`[ref]` is primarily intended for supporting calls to *.NET APIs*** with `ref` / `out` parameters.
- **Its use in pure PowerShell code is unusual and best avoided**, not least due to the awkward invocation syntax.

---

That said, the **difference in behavior with your double type constraint between *positional* and *named* parameter binding is certainly curious** - see [Mathias R. Jessen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) excellent explanation in the comments.

However, **the real problem is that you're even *allowed* to define a *multi*-type constraint (unusual in itself) that involves `[ref]`**, because there appears to be an intentional check to prevent that, yet it doesn't surface in *parameter* declarations.

You can make it surface as follows, however (run this directly at the command line):

```sh
# ERROR, because [ref] cannot be combined with other type constraints.
PS> [ref] [string] $foo = 'bar'

Cannot use [ref] with other types in a type constraint
```

That the same check isn't enforced in *parameter declarations* has been reported in [GitHub issue #16146](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16146).

---

<sup>[1] Behind the scenes, a *generic* type that is *non-public* is used when an actual value is passed with a `[ref]` cast  (`System.Management.Automation.PSReference<T>`), which is instantiated with whatever type the value being cast is. However, this generic type's `.Value` property is still `[object]`-typed, allowing for *modifications* to assign *any* type.</sup>

Comment: While counter-intuitive, it's not so much a bug as a case of one feature ([type coercion of explicitly bound parameter arguments](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/ParameterBinderController.cs#L1286)) "infringing" on the facility for `[ref]` parameters. That being said, I've never encountered any use case that actually required `[ref]` parameters in PowerShell functions :)

Comment: The argument passed in both cases is of type `[PSReference[string]]`. When the argument is explicitly bound by name, the binder _always_ attempts to coerce to the target type, in this case converting `[PSReference[string]]` to `[string]`. It no longer satisfies `[ref]`. When the argument is passed positionally, the binder does _not_ attempt to transform the argument - and since `[PSReference[string]]` is _assignable_ to `[ref]`, no further errors occur.

Comment: Take a look at `$refValue = [ref]""; Trace-Command { MyFunction $refValue; MyFunction -MyRefParam $refValue } -Name ParameterBinding,TypeConversion` - type conversion tracer never makes a peep during the first invocation, because PowerShell never actually attempts to coerce implicitly bound optionals :)

Comment: Thanks. Oops, was sure I tried pure [ref], but clearly not but great explanation. The reason I need it is because I want to track the number of times exceptions are handled in certain areas of code (but not in others), so incrementing an int in the catch and passing back as a ref seemed better form than using a global variable. Any other options?

Comment: @Brett, good question, but I don't think I fully understand your use case; I suggest asking a _new_ question focused just on that - one that isn't focused on one particular approach, so as to avoid an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777).

Comment: I am not able to adequately answer to this as I am on holidays. Nevertheless, your (as usual) nice answer gives a lot background information on why `[ref]` isn't very wel delivered in native PowerShell. I have been a few times in the same situation, and in the end, I think that creating a general custom (hash) table (where every property is a reference)  is the best semantical "solution" to this inquiry. Something like: `$Ref = @{}; Function MyFunction ($MyRefParam) { $Ref[$MyRefParam] = "newValue" }; MyFunction -MyRefParam 'MyRef'`